# Hardware JWT Connection

Tags: jwt, raspberry-pi

I'm currently working on a project that involves using a hardware component using python. The entirety of our REST API is protected with JWT through Firebase. We have a web application that users can access and for them JWT access is easy as it's created on new session and then placed in the body of API calls. However, instantiating a user on the hardware piece to create a token seems either not possible or very messy. As a result, I was wondering how I can call my API and still check that the call is made from a verified source (in this case the hardware component).